# Open a Windows 7 Library in Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, windows-7

How do I open a Windows 7 Library like `Documents`, `Pictures`, `Music`, `Videos` and all other custom libraries from my app?

[image: Libraries]

I tried opening `explorer.exe Libraries\Documents` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-7-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the AppData directory:

```
Dim appData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Find the documents shortcut and open it in explorer:

```
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(appData, "Documents.library-ms", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Process.Start(file)
Next
```

Comment: This also looks like it relies on implementation detail. Surely there's an API for this.

Comment: @David there is a proper API and Obalix has linked to it in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-7-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference) to see how the most common actions are performed on Windows 7 libraries.

**Edit:**

The sample uses the <s>[Windows API Code Pack for Micorosoft .Net Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)</s> **[ edit 2015-09-24:** previous link is dead - use [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24420985/266919) to locate the necessary Nuget packages **]** (thanks [MarkJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj) for pointing out that the link should be there).

As for [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)'s question ...

You use the assign the `ShellLibrary` object to the `DefaultDirectoryShellContainer` property of an `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonFileDialog` (e.g. the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog`).

Comment: +1 for using a [proper API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) rather than relying on implementation details

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not obvious, to me at least, how you would open an explorer at this folder

Comment: @Obalix Programmer wants to open an explorer.exe window at a specific library, not a file dialog.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: execute "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms" on command line to open Documents library.

Comment: The link to "Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft .Net Framework" is broken. There is another SO post about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it

Answer (score 1):

Libraries are stored in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`
and have the extension `.library-ms` so `Documents` would be `Documents.library-ms`

Comment: Ooh, hard coded paths and reliance on implementation details.

Comment: I was just telling them why it wasn't working, its not necessarily the correct way to program it, they were trying to open Libraries\Documents when it should be Libraries\Documents.library-ms

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) provides managed APIs to interact with Windows 7 libraries. I think it might help.

Comment: +1 Although it still looks tricky to use. Code samples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msaleh/archive/2009/08/26/windows-shell-programming-with-windows-api-code-pack.aspx) including one to iterate libraries.

Comment: Just noticed Obalix's answer also links to usage of this API code pack. He links [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65535/Windows-7-Libraries-C-Quick-Reference)

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`

Replace MyDocuments with what ever folder you need, look in the enum to see which ones there are.

Comment: Given that users can create their own, how would you open that (it wouldn't be in the special folder enum)?

Comment: Also, on domain connected machine, this blows up.

Comment: My computer is on a domain and this runs without issue. There may be more to the problem than that.

Answer (score 0):

This is in relation to the comments under LostInLib 's post, as the explanation is too long to put as a comment.

You need to understand the difference between libraries and the documents folder as they are not the same thing. C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents is the default documents folder C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms is the library named Documents, the library is an index of all the locations you add to it, it doesn't have to be linked to C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents , for example on my network I have it set to \server\users\USERNAME , so when users go to the documents library on the start menu they are redirected to the server share. You can also have more than one location in a library so I could have my docs LOCAL in there AND the server my docs, so when I went to the my docs library it would show both folders in one place, so they would appear to be in the same my docs folder.

So presuming my docs is going to be here is not good as it doesn't have to be C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents , in the same way libraries also dont have to be here C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms
if you redirect your appdata folder e.g like on a network your libraries can also be here :
\server\users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms