# ShellExecute to open a special folder (ex: "Libraries\Documents") without knowing the special folder name

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, shellexecute

I'm making an application to backup the opened folders.
The problem is that if in that folders are some special folders (ex: "Desktop", "Computer", "Libraries\Documents", ...) they will not open.

I know that there are constants for those objects, but I don't know which folders will be opened so making a dictionary with all SpecialNames => SpecialConstant is not a good solution for me.

So the question is:
Is there any WinApi function to retrieve the full path from a short name of a special folder?

P.S. Tried both ShellExecute("open", "Path") and ShellExecute("open", "explorer.exe", "Path")
If you paste the names in the explorer they work, but opening them from C++ doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: These are *virtual folders*, provided by a shell namespace extension.  There's no point in backing up virtual folders, focus on the real file system directories on the disk.

Comment: I need to reverse them so I can open them when the user needs to.

Comment: Then I believe you're going to have to construct a table of virtual/actual paths.

Comment: yeah, that's the harder way, because of different versions of windows, etc. I'll wait for some days maybe somebody will suggest something, and then I'll go with the table. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a Windows 7 Library in Windows Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000785/open-a-windows-7-library-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: A part of the answer yes, but I need other folders also (Desktop, Computer, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries are stored in the users `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries` directory as XML files with the names `<libraryname>.library-ms` (e.g. `Pictures.library-ms`.) Opening one of these files with `ShellExecute` opens an Explorer window and shows the library.

Comment: Thanks, this will solve the Library problem, but what about other folders like Desktop, Computer, Control Panel, do you have some suggestion? also I've found a list of special folders in case I'll have to build a dictionary for the rest of them http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13280/How-to-display-Windows-Explorer-objects-in-one-com

Comment: @Spider That CodeProject article has everything you need. Just call ShellExecute on Explorer with the params specified in the table. For example `ShellExecuteW(0, "Open", "Explorer", "/N,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}", "", 1)` should open the Control Panel. Other, real, directories like the Desktop can be gotten he old fashioned way: with [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).