# Getting Windows 7 Library Locations in Java

Tags: java, windows-7, filesystems

I'm trying to list all files found in the Videos Windows 7 library.

First off I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but for the life of me I couldn't find it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000785/open-a-windows-7-library-in-windows-explorer); however, it's for C#. I'm unable to find an analog for Java.

I know the default folder location is here:

C:\Users[USER_NAME_HERE]\Videos

however, the library can contain multiple folders to include. I'm also guessing you could use the registry; however, that's less than ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries are actually XML files, you can access the Video library at

C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Videos.library-ms

The file contains the list of all included folders.